# Flanneld not working in Kubernetes Multinode Example

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flanneld

I am trying to follow this tutorial with two Vagrant instances:
http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode.html

After setting up master and worker node I tried to connect to the service's IP of a simple nginx-service from the master. But it looks like the kube-proxy cannot find the docker-container of the worker-node.

The virtual IP of the service and the container-ip respond well on the worker-node

That made me think of a misfunction of flanneld.
Does anybody know how I could track down this error?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance
Best, Johannes

Output of Kube-Proxy container

> I1016 20:53:42.829290       1 proxysocket.go:130] Accepted TCP connection from 10.0.2.15:51774 to 10.0.2.15:40197
>   E1016 20:53:43.829575       1 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.1.12.3:80: i/o timeout
>   E1016 20:53:45.825473       1 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.1.12.3:80: no route to host
>   E1016 20:53:48.825556       1 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.1.12.3:80: no route to host
>   E1016 20:53:51.825627       1 proxysocket.go:99] Dial failed: dial tcp 10.1.12.3:80: no route to host
>   E1016 20:53:51.825710       1 proxysocket.go:133] Failed to connect to balancer: failed to connect to an endpoint.

Comment: the UDP port 8472 was blocked on our machines, vxlan of flanneld is using this port by default. After unblocking it their was no problem no more. nc -u <ip> <port> helped me

Answer (score 0):

This looks like https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/14426. Try upgrading flannel to 0.5.3.